# Where is the specific address definition of the GPIO IDR register by STM32Cube resulting files?

Tags: stm32, memory-address, gpio

I have read through the explanation of the STM32 project produced by the STM32Cube as in this [website](http://hertaville.com/stm32f0-gpio-tutorial-part-1.html).

From this website, I have learned that: 
In the stm32f0xx.h file, for example, the origianl address of GPIOA is already declared by

"#define GPIOA_BASE         (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000U)"

then all the corresponding registers for GPIOA is declared by

### **"#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)"**

By the information above, this head file has already defined the original adress of GPIOA, and declared the existance of the corresponding registers for GPIOA (like, IDR, MODER, ODR, etc).

But these codes have not defined clearly the address of these GPIOA corresponding registers. For example, GPIOA_IDR address should be defined as 0x40020000 + 0x10 = 0x40020010, but I haven't seen such definitions in the head file.

Where can one find the codes, which define the register addresses of the GOIP corresponding registers?

Comment: From the stm32f0xx.h file, I have found clear definitions of:
1) Basic address of GPIOA as GPIOA_BASE
2) Structure pointer GPIO_TypeDef, which helps us to locate the specific address of each registers of GPIOA, simply by "GPIOA -> IDR". IDR is one of the registers. But I didn't find the codes, which clearly identified the specific addresses of these regsisters. I am looking for codes in the .h file (or other .c files), which looks maybe like:
[[[[[[#define GPIOx_IDR        (GPIOx + 0x10U)]]]]]]]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly defined. The GPIO registers are defined in the struct aliased to the `GPIO_TypeDef` type.

The definition from your question just defines the pointer to the struct of type `GPIO_TypeDef` with address defined by the integer constant `GPIOA_BASE`. When you dereference this pointer by accessing the structure members the compiler knows where in the memory this particular member is.

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;        /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;       /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;      /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;        /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;          /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;          /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;         /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset register,      Address offset: 0x1A */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;         /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];       /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
  __IO uint32_t BRR;          /*!< GPIO bit reset register,               Address offset: 0x28 */
}GPIO_TypeDef;
```

so for example if you derefernce the pointer accessing the OSPEEDR register `GPIOA -> OSPEEDR = 0x4567;` the compiler knows that this member of the struct is at the offset 8 (in bytes - but machine code uses only byte addresses) from the beginning of the struct

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. 
So, what I understand from your answer is that "the compiler automatically knows that the real address of GPIOA_OTYPER as
address of GPIOA_OTYPER = (Address of GPIOA_BASE + Address offset of OTYPER)
The address of GPIOA_BASE is clearly given in the head file, but which codes clearly defined the address offset of the OTYPER=0x04? 
For me, the 
/*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
is only a comment, not a code.

Comment: Not `GPIOA_OTYPER` but  `GPIOA -> OTYPER`

Comment: @ZhengHu The comments reflect what offsets will be used by the compiler. Each field in the struct is of `uint32_t` type. Therefore `GPIOA->MODER` is equivalent to accessing 4 bytes located at `GPIOA_BASE` and `GPIOA->OTYPER` is equivalent to accessing `GPIOA_BASE + 4`, as `OTYPER` is defined as a field located after `MODER` which is 4 bytes long. PS. I'm not touching on the aspect of struct fields padding in this particular case.

Comment: @P__J__ yes, GPIOA -> OTYPER, still I was wondering how the compiler knows that this pointer is poiniting to the specific address for this OTYPER register?  We knows that each register has a unique address, I was looking for codes in the STMCube generated project files, which defines clearly the specific address for the OTYPER register for GPIOx. thank you~

Comment: @JacekŚlimok as the struct members are native uC size, and the base address is always aligned (hardware registers always are)  - no padding will be added at any circumstances

Comment: @P__J__ I know. That's why I've said "I'm not touching on the aspect of struct fields padding *in this particular case*.". I mentioned padding as it's worth pointing out to OP that it's not always as simple as in this case.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok, many thanks! so if I re-rank the order in this struct, like I switch the places of MODER and OTYPER in this typedef struct, then the complier will automatically locate my GPIOA->MODER now in fact to the address as GPIOA_BASE+0x04 (because after switching place, OTYPER is in the first place and MODER is in the second place)? I will try to prove what you said, and it makes sense to me~