# Getting started with STM32 - writing to BSRR

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I recently bought a STM32f031K6 nucleo board and I'm programming it using STMcubeIDE. I have experience with programming 8 bit AVR's so I'm trying to bridge the gap between that and this.

I've been advised that I can write bits by `GPIOA->BSRR &= 1<<0;` but I'm not sure what this syntax is doing,  - am I writing to the register `GPIOA`, or `BSRR`? Which register do I have to watch to see this change take place?

what does the `->` syntax denote?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638459/5708620

Comment: "I have experience with programming 8 bit AVR" then you could try to do some C programming on AVR to learn the link between your assembly and the corresponding C. And then switch to the STM32 which is quite a bit bigger and shouldn't be programmed directly by setting registers like `BSRR`

Comment: The questions about setting outputs on STM32F031 are one thing (which you can find in the corresponding manuals - please google the controller name and familiarize a bit with its documentation first). The question about the `->` operator is a matter of basic C syntax and completely unrelated. Please remove it from this question and have a look at a C textbook or tutorial first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing to the `BSRR` register within the `GPIOA` peripheral.

The `->` operator is C syntax to access members from a pointed to struct, in your instance `GPIOA` is a pointer, `(*GPIOA).BSRR` would be equivalent without the `->` operator.

The peripherals within the STM32, such as GPIOs are memory mapped, `GPIOA` is pointing to the base address of that peripheral within the microcontrollers memory space. This is shown in the following image, taken from the [Reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031936-stm32f0x1stm32f0x2stm32f0x8-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for your processor.

[image]

As @P__J__ quite rightly says in his answer, the `BSRR` register is write only, so you shouldn't be using the `&=` operator, again this is described in the above linked reference manual.

Comment: thanks. if I want to watch GPIOA->BSRR in my debugger/IDE setup, how can i do this? i tried watching 'BSRR' 'GPIOA -> BSRR' doesn't seem to work and GPIOA seems to give me a register but it never seems to change when i write to it

Comment: That’s because it’s write only, look at the ODR instead

Answer (score 2):

You use the BSRR register the wrong way. It is the **write-only** register You can only write to it not read it. If you write the first 16 bits of this register you set the pins. If you write to the last 16 bits you reset the pins. Zero writes are ignored.

So do not use anything except the `=` when you access this register.

`->` if you do not know what it does I can only advice you to start with a good C book. You cant program uCs if you do not know the basics.